# How to set a Environment Variable for Different Customers to Store their Database Connection Details

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, environment-variables

I developed my API Using Node.js,Express,Mysql2 and so on.

This My Database Connection Code

```
// dbConnection.js
require("dotenv").config();
const mysql = require("mysql2");

// Connection

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
});

connection.connect((error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("Connected to Database !");
  }
});

module.exports = connection;
```

This fine for me to store my Connection Details.

i am so confusied about how to store the Customer Connection Details

this is my .Env code

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASSWORD=123456789
DB_DATABASE=sarathi
```